# CakePHP 3.x - Cache VS Configuration

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, configuration

I was wondering what are the differences between configuration (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html) and cache (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html) methods within CakePHP 3.x

I am simply looking to save a single variable called `membershipFee` and I don't think I need to make a database table to save it for the long term as that seems incredibly inefficient.

Which one is better for my purpose?

Comment: You should describe your purpose and its requirements in more detail.

Comment: Obviously a cache is not a permanent storage for configuration data, as the name cache implies. So write it to a persistent configuration (file).